# Installed cd-hit (using conda) for Jupyter Notebook but command not found?

Tags: python, bash, jupyter-notebook, conda

I installed the package cd-hit in a Jupyter notebook. It seems successfully installed.

```
conda install -c bioconda cd-hit
```

However when I try to run cd-hit I get the error `command not found`

I am using

```
%%bash 
cd-hit -i input.fasta -o output.fasta -c .99
```

I have also tried without the `%%bash`. Am I missing something? Should I be adding `cd-hit` to a Path somewhere? Should I be using a conda environment in Jupyter notebook rather than just directly using conda install? Thank you.

Comment: Where did you run your `conda install` command? Explicitly the command should be `%conda install -c bioconda cd-hit` in a cell. Restarted the kernel after install? What sort of machine are you working on? Windows wouldn't be expected to work with `%%bash`. Is it saying that isn't available? Or `cd-hit`? Make your attempts simpler. Just try to see if you can get the 'Usage' info to show with `!cd-hit -h`. If it doesn't work show what you get by pasting text here under an 'Update' section. For example, you say `I have also tried without the %%bash.` Yet, you don't say what actually happend.

Comment: <continued> Maybe for comparison for trouble shooting it would be helpful to have a place where it works? Go to [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/conda) and click on the `launch binder` badge. When the session spins up and shows you a notebook, make a new cell and enter `%conda install -c bioconda cd-hit`. When that completes installing, restart the kernel, and then make another new cell and run `!cd-hit -h`.